# Open port for all VPCs in AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services

My requirement is :
For a given AWS account,automate to open a port xyz for all the VPCs of that account for a cidr x.x.x.x/x.Later we would like to apply the same for all the other aws accounts from aws organizations.

My approach is using boto3 api....Get the list of all the VPCs of given account,get it's attached SGs and NACLs and attach the required rule.

Or other solution is as per documentation given for aws network firewall.

I am here to know if there are any better ideas of implementing this.

Thankyou!

Comment: This would typically be done during the normal DevOps automation for your apps. If you do it outside of your normal deployment tooling then it might be undone later. Also, don't change NACLs unless you have to (you should not typically need to).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to "open a port for VPCs".

Each resource attached to an Amazon VPC is associated with Security Group(s). You would need to **add an Inbound rule** to a Security Group to permit access to a resource.

I would **highly recommend *against* blindly opening a particular port for all resources**. It is much more secure to only open access to specific resources that require that access.

Echoing @jarmod's advice, in general **you should not modify NACL rules** unless you have a *very* specific reason to do so (eg for creating a DMZ). Security Groups provide adequate access control for the majority of situations.